# Is there any way to “downclock” a video card that regularly overheats?

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

My Nvidia 8600M GT video card seems to be dying. It freezes the laptop after intense use, then if I restart the display doesn’t work right anymore (it shows some random vertical bands). I have to shut it down and wait until it cools down, then it works again.

I had some issues with the video card before, “Display driver stopped responding and has recovered…” errors but only now it started to freeze the system and fail after restart.

The computer is pretty old (almost 6 years). Is there any way to “downclock” the video card? Maybe this way it doesn’t get hot and doesn’t freeze?

I’ll buy a new computer next week but until then I need this one in order to finish my work.

Comment: Have you checked the temperatures with something like [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)?  You might have better success with opening up your laptop and using compressed air to remove any dust and debris.

Comment: Have you cleaned the dirt out?  Its unlikely downclocking will do anything to prevent this since the GPU will still eventually overheat.

Answer (score 2):

MSI Afterburner should allow to do this: https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner, provided it recognizes the videocard. You should be able to adjust the fan speed up, and core clock/memory clock down.

Hope this helps.